# How I can use the CSV data into Jmeter webdriver script?

Tags: jmeter

I want to test my application with 5-10 different users, I wrote the webdriver script for login the application but i dunno how i can different concurrent user name using CSV data config in Jmeter. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**: via "Parameters" section:

[image: WebDriver Parameters]

---

**Option 2**: via [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class (check out [Using Java From Scripts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html) article)

```
var vars = org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables()

var username = vars.get('username')
var password = vars.get('password')
```

See [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) guide for WebDriver Sampler tips and tricks